# One GPU for compute, another to power display

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-quadro

I have a Quadro M6000 (24GB) I'd like to utilize solely for processing. I have another card, a GTX 1080, that I'd like to use solely to drive the display. This system will be running Windows 10.

I'm wondering what the easiest way to do this would be -- install the GTX 1080 first, get the drivers installed for that, and then add the M6000?

Any and all advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to not attach a monitor to the M6000 and not to extend
the desktop to it, and you should then be able to use it for computing
without hanging the display.

The M6000 24GB is in the [CUDA GPUs list](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), so it should be usable for GPU compute.
Be careful to use the latest Nvidia drivers.

If you are writing your own compute program, you will need to use the
[CUDA Toolkit](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html).